# The SKAction does not repeat forever

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

The bellow code is not repeating inspite of explicitly setting the SKAction  as repeatActionForever.

```
SKAction *action = [SKAction moveToY:self.frame.size.height + bullet.size.height duration:2];
SKAction *remove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
SKAction *fireForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[action,remove]]];
[bullet runAction:fireForever];
```

The bullet just fires once , when its expected to be fired every 1 second.

Comment: You are removing the bullet node from parent and not creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the bullet from the parent, that's why it's not firing again,
What you should do is create a method to create a bullet - fire it - destroy it, and create an SKAction  that uses this method.

```
-(void)FireBullet
{
    //create bullet
    //fire it
    //remove from parent
}
```

and add the following code when you want the bullets to start firing.

```
SKAction *myAction = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(FireBullet) onTarget:self];
SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:myAction];
[self runAction:forever];
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Or he can change remove action into a change in position back to the origin.

Comment: @Andriko13 's solution is valid as well